# How to avoid the clearing of listview while switching between one activity to another activity

Tags: android, listview

I am using a an adapter function which will view the current location in the list view.

The list view is working fine, my problem is while switching to another activity and returning to the same activity my list is clear and it's starting from first what can I do for.Thanks in advance.

The below code is my Intent activity.
From this only I have switched between two activities.

My adapter is

```
Adapter = new MyTrip_listview_Adapter(MyTrip.this, location, Date_Array, imagesview, j, context, arrayplaces);
listViewplace.setAdapter(adapter);
listViewplace.setSelection(location.size() - 1);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The below code is my Intent activity.
From this only I have switch between two activity.

Here how can do the activity switching

```
home_lay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
    }
});
trips_lay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent home_btn = new Intent(MyTrip.this, Trips_visited.class);
        startActivity(home_btn);
    }
});
notifi_lay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent home_btn = new Intent(MyTrip.this, Notification_from_friends.class);
        startActivity (home_btn);
    }
});
sett_lay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you put the Adapter code, it seems like you put it in onResume/onStart or something.

Just use this:

```
if (adapter == null) {
    adapter = new MyTrip_listview_Adapter(MyTrip.this, location, Date_Array, imagesview, j, context, arrayplaces);
    listViewplace.setAdapter(adapter); 
    listViewplace.setSelection(location.size() - 1); 
} else {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply i am using the adapter in the method after getting the valuses

Comment: @hari and is there any reason to get the values every time the Activity is shown? you should do it only in onCreate() or just use the code I added and it'll work anyway.

Comment: i want to view the values in list view still the user exits the application

Comment: @hari update your question with the full Activity code. No way to further assist you without it.

Comment: @hari saw the updated question... you should use my code instead of your adapter... if "adapter" is always null, make sure you're not manually setting it to null somewhere in the Activity

Comment: kk i should implement it in onCreate or in onresume

Comment: @hari You can use both... but unless you update your data source onResume, you should use onCreate

Answer (score 0):

when you call another activity, u could set a flag on that intent so that it has multiple tasks.

```
Intent home_btn = new Intent(MyTrip.this, Trips_visited.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(home_btn);
```

If you want to go back to the activity with listview when u exit the app.
You'd have to catch the back press.

you could override onkeydown and also add moveTaskToBack(true)

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                moveTaskToBack(true);

            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

add this to your first activity.

Comment: can elabrate the coding please i dont where to implement this

Comment: put this
home_btn.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
After 
Intent home_btn = new Intent(MyTrip.this, Trips_visited.class);
on Both onclick listeners
and just copy and paste 
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                moveTaskToBack(true);

            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
to your MyTrip.java